# Web server monitoring software for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, monitoring

I am wondienrg what is a good monitoring software for a cloud hosted ubuntu server.

I would like to monitor:

1. Traffic statistics to my website
2. Scripts/Areas of maximum load
3. Overall server load
4. Uptime and downtime issues etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple:

1. [AWFFull](http://www.stedee.id.au/awffull/) - A webalizer fork (and [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/))
2. Same as 1
3. [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) and [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
4. Same as 3

Munin is great and very easy to add plugins to graph exactly what
you want, it also got good interface to talk to Nagios.

Comment: thumbs up for munin & nagios.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 and 2, I like either analog or Google Analytics.  For 3 and 4 I like nagios.

Answer (score 0):

- For 1 and 2: Awstats, Webalizer or Google Analytics
- for 3 and 4: Nagios, [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org) or Munin